# Why $\ln n<n^{1/4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

In Calculus Book of "THOMAS" page 561 Twelfth Edition, I found this example

**Example 3** $\quad$ Does $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}}$ converge?

**Solution** $\quad$ Because $\ln n$ grows more slowly than $n^c$ for any positive constant $c$ (Section $10.1,$ Exercise $105$), we can compare the series to a convergent $p$-series. To get the $p$-series, we see that $$\frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}} \lt \frac{n^{1/4}}{n^{3/2}} = \frac 1{n^{5/4}}$$
for $n$ sufficiently large. Then taking $a_n = (\ln n)/n^{3/2}$ and $b_n = 1/n^{5/4}$, we have

$$\begin{align} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} & = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^{1/4}}\\ \\ & = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1/n}{(1/4)n^{-3/4}}\tag{l'Hospital's Rule}\\ \\ &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 4{n^1/4} = 0\end{align}$$

---

I couldn't understand how the $\ln n<n^{1/4}$. Any help?

Comment: In exercise 105 of section 10.1, it was shown that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^c} = 0$$ for all $c > 0$. Pick $c = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Indeed, we have $(\log x)^{a} = o(x^{b})\big|_{x \to \infty}$ for all pairs of $a, b > 0.$ Taking $a := 1$ and $b := 1/4,$ we have $\log x < x^{1/4}$ for large $x$.

Comment: The logarithm loses to all positive powers of $x$. Never forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that $\ln n < n^{1/4}$ for all positive integers $n$, but $\ln n < n^{1/4}$ for $n$ *sufficiently large*. This means that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $\ln n < n^{1/4}$ for all $n \ge N$. To see this, use the fact

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^{1/4}} = 0.$$

Given $\epsilon = 1$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{\ln n}{n^{1/4}} < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. Thus $\ln n <  n^{1/4}\epsilon = n^{1/4}$ for all $n\ge N$.

Alternatively, you could use $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x} = 0$. For given $\epsilon = \frac{1}{4}$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $\ln x < \epsilon x$ for all $x \ge k$. Then if $x \ge k^4$, $\ln x^{1/4} < \epsilon x^{1/4} = \frac{1}{4}x^{1/4}$, i.e., $\frac{1}{4}\ln x < \frac{1}{4}x^{1/4}$. Hence $\ln x < x^{1/4}$ for all $x \ge k^4$.